# Use of elasticsearches synonym filter's expand and lenient properties

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-synonym

Can anyone explain with an example, In synonym filter use of **expand** and **lenient** attributes.
I went through [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-synonym-tokenfilter.html) but still, I didn't get it. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Best way to understand Elasticsearch concepts is by testing it on some test index.**

`lenient` true, Ignore the errors as explained in the same document, you can change the param to `false` and try to create the index with same request

```
{
    "settings": {
        "index": {
            "analysis": {
                "analyzer": {
                    "synonym": {
                        "tokenizer": "standard",
                        "filter": [
                            "my_stop",
                            "synonym"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "filter": {
                    "my_stop": {
                        "type": "stop",
                        "stopwords": [
                            "bar"
                        ]
                    },
                    "synonym": {
                        "type": "synonym",
                        "lenient": false, // Note this
                        "synonyms": [
                            "foo, bar => baz"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You will get following error from Elasticsearch

```
"reason": "Invalid synonym rule at line 1",
            "caused_by": {
                "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
                "reason": "term: bar was completely eliminated by analyzer"
            }
```

**Error message is very clear, bar was added to stop words list which will be executed before `synonym` filter and removes `bar` from token filter hence it's not available for `synonym` filter.**